# In React, how do I listen to a router.transitionTo() from the page it is transitioning to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say I'm on Page A with Component A. I click a button in my Header Component and I am sent to Page B with Component B (using `react-router.transitionTo()`). Then I press the same button and nothing happens.

I have tried listening from Component B's `componentWillRecieveProps`, and even added this line to B's `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUpdate()`:

`this.getDOMNode().addEventListener('transitionend', this.willTransitionTo, false);`

with my own `willTransitionTo` method. However, none of the above works.

I have thought of a workaround, where when I click on the button I call a store method that emits something to alert Component B that the button has been pressed. But before I go that route, I want to make sure there isn't a proper way to do this.

Comment: I've been having the same problem recently, and I haven't found any workaround either. I like your store idea though.